# vs 2013: Source Control List location

Tags: visual-studio-2013, accurev

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question, so forgive me if it is not.
Our group uses Accurev (AccurBridge) for our source control.

I wanted to know where the vs 2013 source control list is read from? VS is not detection all my source control options all the time, so I would like to make sure that this folder is always in the list.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you'll install TFS source control explorer extension:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/af70cbb7-1e0d-4d16-bc57-cccc15370c51

Which includes the following features:

1. Move to Folder
2. Branch to Folder
3. Merge from Sources File icon change
4. Drag & Drop
5. Show / hide deleted items
6. Destroy
7. Source Control changes and fixes

**Update** Since you added you are using Accurev - go to AccuRev menu and choose Workspace Information.
There you'll see the attribute "Accurev_BIN" which display the folder where AccuRev read its source controlled files.

I hope that support your question.

Comment: I should have put that my groups uses Accurev. I have the plugin installed, and sometimes it is detected and others not.